# AndEngine GLES2 scale without touching corner

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, andengine

I want to scale this file

[image]

to create rectangles with diffrent sizes without cutting it to 4 or 9 peace. I know that in iOS it is possible, but it is in andengine? How I can tell to andengine "scale only green part"?

Comment: Take a look at 9-patch images.

Comment: @dcharms but this is android element or andengine?

Comment: @dcharms add anwser so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android (and AndEngine) use 9-patch images to do this type of scaling.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch